# Reduce Image load Time

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax

I have a problem of image loading. My site contains around 20 images on home page. It will take to much time to load.

So is there any code in asp.net framework 3.5 that will reduce the load time without jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Images are loaded by the client browser and cached for subsequent requests. So you could prefetch them using javascript. There's not much you could do on the server side other than of course reduce the number of those images, but I don't think that this is an option :-)

You could also take a look at a technique called [CSS Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

Answer (score 1):

"is there any code in asp.net framework 3.5 that will reduce the load time"

No.

However
1) what kind of images are we talking about? Content image or Layout images? If they are layout images then you can combine the images together and use CSS to position them appropriately. This will reduce the number of requests made for images.

2) what sort of file size are we talking about with these images? 10k? 20k? 100k? You can run the images through smushit to reduce the file size.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/